# MySQL counting gender instances

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have the following MySQL query.

```
USE demo;
SELECT 
  loc.name,
  sum(case cr_sex when 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as 'F#', 
  sum(case cr_sex when 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as 'M#'
FROM case_report_main as cr 
JOIN location as loc on cr.cr_name = loc.name
GROUP BY loc.name
```

this works the way I want to, it counts each occurrence of each gender and groups it by the location name. But when I try to join it with another table

```
USE demo;
SELECT 
  loc.name,
  sum(case cr_sex when 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as 'F#', 
  sum(case cr_sex when 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as 'M#'
FROM case_report_main as cr 
JOIN location as loc on cr.cr_name=loc.name
JOIN map_polygons as mp on mp.polygon_name=loc.name
GROUP BY loc.name
```

the values get completely messed up, returning thousands instead of the expected tens and hundreds.

I **think** I understand the problem, the additional table increases the number of rows. I am not sure how to fix this though or if this is actually the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because there might be records that have multiple matches on table `map_polygons` causing to have invalid counts on gender, try putting the first query in a subquery,

```
SELECT  mp.*,
        loc.name
        loc.`F#`
        loc.`M#`
FROM
        (
            SELECT  loc.name,
                    sum(case cr_sex when 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as 'F#', 
                    sum(case cr_sex when 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as 'M#'
            FROM case_report_main as cr 
            JOIN location as loc on cr.cr_name = loc.name
            GROUP BY loc.name
        ) loc
        INNER JOIN map_polygons mp on mp.polygon_name=loc.name
```

by the way,since it's mysql, it ispossible to sum up boolean result to make it shorter

```
SELECT  mp.*,
        loc.name
        loc.`F#`
        loc.`M#`
FROM
        (
            SELECT  loc.name,
                    sum(cr_sex = 'F') as 'F#', 
                    sum(cr_sex = 'M') as 'M#'
            FROM case_report_main as cr 
            JOIN location as loc on cr.cr_name = loc.name
            GROUP BY loc.name
        ) loc
        INNER JOIN map_polygons mp on mp.polygon_name=loc.name
```

Comment: Yep, that seems to have worked. Thanks! 
I guess need to work on my understanding of subqueries.
Salamat kabayan.

Comment: no problem kabayan. here's also a good article about join, if you need one. [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the map_polygon table, is ur polygon_name unique? Is thats not unique, you might need a chnage in the select fields

```
SELECT 
  loc.name,
  count(distinct case cr_sex when 'F' then cr.id else null end) as 'F#', 
  count(distinct case cr_sex when 'M' then cr.id else null end) as 'M#'
FROM case_report_main as cr 
JOIN location as loc on cr.cr_name=loc.name
JOIN map_polygons as mp on mp.polygon_name=loc.name
GROUP BY loc.name
```